# Angular 2 ag-grid update columns changing *ngFor array

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have this grid that works .

```
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
            [rowData]="lines" enableColResize enableSorting enableFilter groupHeaders suppressRowClickSelection toolPanelSuppressGroups
            toolPanelSuppressValues rowHeight="22" rowSelection="multiple">
            <ag-grid-column headerName="#" [width]="30" [checkboxSelection]="true" [suppressSorting]="true" [suppressMenu]="true" [pinned]="true"></ag-grid-column>
            <ag-grid-column *ngFor="let header of visibleColumns" headerName="{{header.label}}" field="{{header.name}}" ></ag-grid-column>
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

But when I update the visibleColumns array, I thought ngfor will update automatically the columns and rows.
Currently the header doesn't update properly and still remains the old one. How can i manage to update my table with dynamic columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic grid & column definition is not possible when using the declarative style, as you are here.

You have two option for dynamic column creation:

- Use a mix of declarative and programmatic methods. Use what you have for what isn't dynamic and for the dynamic parts use the api & columnApi to create/remove/update columns dynamically
- Use the programmatic style throughout

I'd suggest the first might be the way you want to go, but this may be subjective.